# hunspell: add word to dictionary from command line

Tags: spell-checking, hunspell

From [hunspell man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/hunspell/):

```
...
    When in the -a mode, hunspell will also accept lines  of  single
    words  prefixed  with  any of '*', '&', '@', '+', '-', '~', '#',
    '!', '%', '`', or '^'.  A line starting with '*' tells  hunspell
    to  insert the word into the user's dictionary (similar to the I
    command).
...
```

I tried something like: `echo "* my_word" | hunspell -a` but the word is not in my dictionary as parsing sample file again shows it as misspelled word

How does this work, how can I add custom word?
Or with Aspell, or any "common" program that writes to compatible dictionaries read by Hunspell/Aspell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think instead of `(similar to the I command)` it should be `(similar to the A command)`:

```
A

Accept the word for the rest of this hunspell session.
```

Let's check the `man` page again:

```
The -a option is intended to be used from other programs through a pipe.
In this mode, hunspell prints a one-line version identification message,
and then begins reading lines of input.
```

So, when in `-a mode`, `hunspell` session ends after reading and processing the last line of input. Furthermore,

```
When in the -a mode, hunspell will also accept lines of single words prefixed
with any of '*', '&', '@', '+', '-', '~', '#', '!', '%', ''', or '^'. A line
starting with '*' tells hunspell to insert the word into the user's dictionary
(similar to the I command)[........] A line prefixed with '#' will cause the
personal dictionary to be saved.
```

Prefixing a single word line with `*` (note there should be no space between word and prefix) will add that word to the user's dictionary but only for the current `hunspell` session, since, as per the `man` page, only a line prefixed with `#` will cause the personal dictionary to be saved (the on-disk file, that is). Hence running

```
echo "*goosfraba" | hunspell -a
```

does absolutely nothing. `hunspell` adds *goosfraba* to the dictionary for this session then exits (no other lines to process). You have to add a second line prefixed with `#` in order to save the recently added word(s):

```sh
echo -e "*goosfraba\n#" | hunspell -a
```

Let's see:

::spell-checking *goosfraba*:

```
echo -e "goosfraba" | hunspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.2.06 (but really Hunspell 1.3.2)
& goosfraba 1 0: goofball
```

& = `Word` is not in the dictionary, there is one near miss: *goofball*.

::adding goosfraba to the dictionary then spell-checking during the same `hunspell` session (two lines):

```
echo -e "*goosfraba\ngoosfraba" | hunspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.2.06 (but really Hunspell 1.3.2)
*
```

* = `Word` is in the dictionary.

::spell-checking *goosfraba* again (new `hunspell` session):

```
echo -e "goosfraba" | hunspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.2.06 (but really Hunspell 1.3.2)
& goosfraba 1 0: goofball
```

& = Again, `word` is not in the dictionary (nothing was saved during the previous session)

::adding goosfraba to the dictionary and saving during the same `hunspell` session (two lines):

```
echo -e "*goosfraba\n#" | hunspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.2.06 (but really Hunspell 1.3.2)
```

::spell-checking *goosfraba* again (new `hunspell` session):

```
echo "goosfraba" | hunspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.2.06 (but really Hunspell 1.3.2)
*
```

* = `Word` is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that easiest solution is to use Aspell and create custom file in home folder, named [.aspell.lang.pws](http://aspell.net/man-html/Format-of-the-Personal-and-Replacement-Dictionaries.html#Format-of-the-Personal-and-Replacement-Dictionaries), with contents like:

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 0
my_word
```

for language "en", which seems like great way to share "portable dictionary", BTW