# Adding words to Hunspell dictionary of Typora Markdown Editor in terminal at least

Tags: spell-checking, hunspell

How to add words to a specific Hunspell dictionary? I am trying to add words to the dictionary, but it doesn't work. Not from terminal nor from application `Typora` that uses  the dictionary.

```
root@lokal:/home/s/Dropbox/blog# ls -Alrt /usr/share/typora/resources/app/node_modules/spellchecker/vendor/hunspell_dictionaries
total 2252
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   2406 Sep 12 04:28 README.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  11818 Sep 12 04:28 en_US.aff
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 758364 Sep 19 21:15 en_US.dic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      9 Sep 21 11:36 .dic_delta
root@lokal:/home/s/Dropbox/blog#
```

Method found in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79915/204439

```
root@lokal:/home/s/Dropbox/blog# echo -e "*Nginx\n#" | hunspell -a
bash: /usr/bin/hunspell: No such file or directory
root@lokal:/home/s/Dropbox/blog#
```

doesn't work. I installed Hunspell, but then the dictionary in the path of Typora, shown above, was not loaded.

How to add words to the dictionary in terminal? Even better how to add words in Typora Markdown Editor? The normal way using Typora menu works only for one session.